# How to query on array of struct column in AWS Athena? (parquet format)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, parquet, amazon-athena

I have a array of struct column in table reports.
(array<struct< key:string,value:string>>)
the columns data look like

```
labels
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{key=name, value=cat}, {key=owner, value=meow}, {key=team, value=animal}]`
[]
[{key=name, value=leopard}]
```

How can I query this where I wanted to find records which has key=name and value=cat, and key=owner and value=meow. (i mean the first example).

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link. This is cloudtrail logs, where we have struct columns
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html

Refer to the userIdentity column
Also check below link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/rows-and-structs.html

You can directly reference nested fields with a parent_field.child_field notation. Try:

```
SELECT
  my_field,
  my_field.a,
  my_field.b,
  my_field.c.d,
  my_field.c.e
FROM 
  my_table
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: The problem I am facing is I am having multiple keys and values inside the labels column. while on unnesting and cross joining it create separate raws then combined query is failing.

Comment: I wanted to get the first record in the example out of 3.